# Exercise about structure theorem for finitely generated module

Tags: modules, finitely-generated

> Let $K$ be a algebraically closed field with $char(K) = p$. For integer $r>0$ and $c_0, c_r \neq0$, let $f(X)$ be a $K$-coefficient polynomial with $p^r$ degree,
>
> $f(X)=c_0X+c_1X^p+...+c_rX^{p^r} $.
>
> We let denote $f^k(X)$ composition of $f$ with k-times.
>
> Let $A$ be a $F_p[T]$ ($F_p$ is a prime field). We define action of $A$ to $K$ as follows. For $a= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k T^k \in A$ and $x \in K$,
>
> $ax = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k f^k(x)$.
>
> From this action, $K$ is a $A$-module. We let denote $V_a= \{ x \in K|ax=0 \}$ for $a \in A$.
>
> (1) If $a\neq 0$, then $V_a$ is finitely generated $A$-module.
>
> (2) Suppose $a = T$. Find structure of $V_a$ as $A$-module with following format
>
> $V_a \simeq A^{\bigoplus m} \bigoplus (A/a_1A) \bigoplus (A/a_2A) \bigoplus ... \bigoplus (A/a_lA)$.
>
> (this means get $a_i$ explicitely)
>
> (3) Show $K$ is not finitely generated $A$-module.

My approach

(1) $ax$ is a polynomial with $(p^r)^n$ degree. Since $K$ is algebraically closed, the number of element of $V_a$ is at most $(p^r)^n$. Hence finitely generated $A$-module.

(2) From structure theorem on PID
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), we can describe $V_a$ as above. However, I cannot determine each $a_i$.

(3) Maybe consider cover of $K$ by several $V_a$ and get contradiction somehow.

Thank you.

Comment: I see at least two typos. For one, if $V_a = \{x \in K \,|\, ax = 0 \}$ for $a \in K,$ then $V_a = \{0\}$: $K$ is a field, so the Zero Product Property holds, i.e., if $ax = 0,$ then either $a = 0$ or $x = 0.$ Further, the third questions says to show that $K$ is *not* finitely generated over $A$; however, your suggestion seems to indicate that you believe that $K$ *is* finitely generated over $A.$

Comment: I am also skeptical about your proof of the first question. By definition, it is true that $a \cdot x = a_0 + a_1 f(x) + \cdots + a_k f^k(x),$ hence for each $x \in V_a,$ we have that $a_0 + a_1 f(x) + \cdots + a_k f^k(x) = 0$; however, I cannot justify your use of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra because $x$ is not an indeterminate.

Comment: Dear Carlo, Thanks for reply. (1) your comment about first typo is right. $a \in A$ (2) second typo is not right. Original sentence say K is not finitely generated A-module. My approach means get contradiction by finite cover. (3) my approach to first question seems right in my opinion. There is a morphism from $F_p$ to $K$, so we can see element of $F_p$ as one of $K$. Each term of the equation $a_0 + a_1 f(x) + \cdots + a_k f^k(x) = 0$ is something like $(a_l \cdot c_m \cdot x^n)$ (no mean to index set), so $(a_l \cdot c_m) \in K$ and get result.

Comment: I see that you added the phrase "get a contradiction somehow," so that makes more sense now. On the matter of the first question, I am still not convinced.